# Is it easier to get Schengen visa (Germany) if i had been issued in the past?

Tags: schengen, filipino-citizens, application-status

I was approved Schengen thru German embassy and travelled to Germany and other EU countries in 2018. Is there a greater chance that I will be approved again for the second time? I'm holding a PH passport. I'm kind of worried as my companion already got his passport back with visa while mine has not been returned. We applied the same day.

Comment: When did you make the application?

Answer (score 3):

We can't really help with your specific worries, but it's easy to consider the effects of your visa history on your application.  Having s prior visa means that you are *less unknown,* so (most likely) less of a risk.  Of course, it's also possible for your history to work against you, for example if you

- overstayed,
- changed your itinerary from the one submitted in your application, or
- made your second application very soon after your first trip.

If none of those things happened, nor anything else untoward, your history probably helps your present application.

The delay could be for any of several reasons, including (I speculate) extra checking for you on account of your history.  Try not to worry about it.  There's nothing you can do at this point, anyway.